# How to serialize Exception

Tags: ruby

According to [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/Exception.html) and [apidock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Exception/json_create/class), you can serialize and deserialize an exception using `to_json` and `json_create`.

But after having wasted some time trying to use them, I still haven't found a way.

Calling `exc.to_json` gives me an empty hash, and `Exception.json_create(hash)` gives me this error: `undefined method 'json_create' for Exception:Class`

I guess I could easily recreate those functions since the source is available, but I'd rather understand what I'm doing wrong... Any idea?

Comment: You may need to extend the Exception class to handle this better. What does `JSON.dump(e)` for an exception do?

Comment: `JSON.dump(e)` gives me the same empty hash (in rails console, but throws an error in irb).

I could indeed just use the source code found in the links I put, it seems to work ok. What I don't understand is why I have to do it while those functions are supposed to be there already.

Comment: You have to `require 'json'`, have you done so? Even then, `to_json` only serializes the message by default. Adding Rails to the mix (I didn't see the Rails tag) may further complicate issues.

Comment: You may need to write a converter of Exception to Hash, or patch in a method on Exception that `JSON.dump` uses, like `to_hash`.

Comment: @dave yes, I did require json, but JSON.dump still raised an exception. The thing is, according to the documentation, to_json actually should create a hash containing message and backtrace, but does not

Comment: @user3033467 Again, under Rails, behavior is likely different. Under a plain irb the message is indeed serialized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The JSON module doesn't extend Exception by default. You have to `require "json/add/exception"`. This is documented in the [JSON Additions](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/exts/json/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-JSON+Additions) section of the Ruby JSON module docs.

```
require "json/add/exception"
 
begin
  nil.foo
rescue => exception
  ex = exception
end

json = ex.to_json
puts json
# => {"json_class":"NoMethodError","m":"undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass","b":["prog.rb:5:in `<main>'"]}
```

Check out [`ext/json/lib/json/add` in the Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/master/ext/json/lib/json/add) to see which classes work this way. If you do `require "json/add/core"` it will load JSON extensions for Date, DateTime, Exception, OpenStruct, Range, Regexp, Struct, Symbol, Time, and others.

To reverse the process, you can pass the `create_additions: true` option to `JSON.parse`:

```
p JSON.parse(json, create_additions: true)
# => #<NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass
#
#      nil.foo
#         ^^^^>
```

Comment: So my first stack question ever turned out to be really stupid... Thanks for the answer

Comment: It's really not a stupid question. Like I said, it doesn't appear to be documented; I only figured it out by digging in the Ruby source. Even tadman and DaveNewton didn't know the answer off the top of their heads, and they have twice as much rep as me!

Comment: not stupid at all, I've been using ruby for years and wouldn't have figured this out, glad I came accross it!

Comment: and someone should probably send a doc patch to ruby or something.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Jordan is correct. If you have a case eg. that you need to serialize an Exception and send to to ActiveJob where you want to reconstruct it, then you need to use `.as_json` method.

```
require "json/add/exception"

begin
  nil.foo
rescue => exception
  ex = exception
end

puts ex.to_json.class
# => String

string = ex.to_json
puts Exception.json_create(string).message
# => m

puts ex.as_json.class
# => Hash

hash = ex.as_json
puts Exception.json_create(hash).message
# => undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass
```

You need to read the [source code](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/Exception.html) to understand why `Exception.json_create(string).message`returns `m` :)

Answer (score 2):

It's also important to note that the `Exception.json_create` example doesn't keep the error class.

```
Exception.json_create(JSON.parse(ArgumentError.new('error').to_json))
# => #<Exception: error>
```

Try instead:

```
require "json/add/exception"

def deserialize_exception(json)
  hash = JSON.parse(json)
  hash['json_class'].constantize.json_create(hash)
end
```